# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'GamesState'

Tags: python, pygame, attributes, chess

I am currently making a chess game. I have started to try and draw the board. I've started making the board and where the pieces will go. I wanted to run the code to see whether it works and I ended up getting the error.

I am also using Eddie Sharick on youtube to help me make my code. For some reason it works for him but not for me. I'm not sure whether its because we are using different python versions.

Link to his tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnYui0e73Rs

AtttributeError:"function" object has no attribute
"GamesState".

My first file called chess main:

```
"""
This is the main driver file. It will be responsible for handling user input and displaying the current gamesState object
"""

import pygame as p
from chess import ChessEngine

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512 #400 is another option
DIMENSION = 8 #dimensions of a chess board are 8x8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15 #for animations later on
IMAGES = {}

"""
Initialize a global dictionary of images. This will be called exactly once in the main
"""
def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bQ' ]
    for piece in pieces:`enter code here`
        IMAGES["piece"] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        #You can access an image by saying "images ["wp"]"
'''
The main driver four our code. This will handle user input and updating the graphics
'''
def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    print(gs.board)
```

My second file called ChessEngine:

```
"""""
This class is responsible for storing all the information about the current state of a chess game.
It will also responsible for determining the valid moves at the current state. It will also keep a move log.
"""""
class GamesState():
    def __init__(self):
        # board is an 8 x 8 2d list, each element of the list
        # is a 2-character string.
        # 1st character "w" or "b" - piece color # 2nd character = "R", "N", "B", "Q", "K", "P"
        self.board = [
            ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wN", "wR"]]
        self.whiteToMove = True
        self.moveLog = []
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pj/PycharmProjects/Chess Game/ChessMain.py", line 34, in <module>
     main()
  File "/home/pj/PycharmProjects/Chess Game/ChessMain.py", line 31, in main
   gs = chess_engines.GamesState()
AttributeError: type object 'ChessEngine' has no attribute 'GamesState'
```

Comment: The class is called `GameState` and you try to access `GamesState`.  Additionally there's an error in your `GameState` class. You defined the function as `_init_`, but it's called `__init__` (magic methods have double underscores).

Comment: I can't find anywhere in your main file the line the error refers to, `gs = chess_engines.GamesState()`, are you certain you're running the correct file? Also, considering the class in your second file is called GameState, not GamesState, you should fix the typo in your code.

Comment: @Matthias I made the changes you where talking about but the same error continues to occur.

Comment: @OttoHanski gs = chess_engines.GamesState() i think its supposed to be linked with GamesState class

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your missing the import in your ChessMain.py file.
Try to add the following:

```
from ChessEngine import GameState
```

So your class will be known in the main-file.

Also you should watch out for name convention of your files, seems like you're importing the ChessEngine from the python chess-library, but you called your second file ChessEngine.py. That could lead to problems.

Comment: from ChessEngine import GameState I added this code but it still comes with the same error. I will change the name of my file.

Comment: Make sure the names match, as you edited it to "GamesState".

Comment: Yes i have changed them all to "GamesState"